# Access certificate private key from PHP, certificate key stored in windows certificate store

Tags: php, certificate, key, store

We have an requirement to make SOAP calls using certificates in our PHP application, we need a way to read the private key stored in windows certificate store. The environment comprises of windows 2008 R2, IIS 7.

Whats our best option for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can export the encrypted, password protected, certificate from Windows, convert it to a format that PHP can read, and leave it on the web server where PHP is running.

PHP can read RSA encrypted (base 64 encoded) X.509 certificates and private keys.

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-decrypt.php.

I've done this in the past.

Comment: the client requirements are to store all certificates in the windows certificate store, cant by pass their enterprise security policies and practices

Comment: Could we specify under IIS to attach the signed certificate in the headers for an external link accessed using web.config? 
PHP -> IIS -> attach signed certificate in the headers -> web service?

Comment: @OpenProjDevel, is your PHP running on the same Windows server/IIS? Is the issue where the certs are stored, because the export would just be a copy. Do you need the whole cert or just the key? Please provide more details.

Comment: @OpenProjDevel, what are you trying to do? If PHP is on the same Windows server, you can always write your own PHP extension, using native code to read the cert or use the experimental .NET extension. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dotnet-load.php

Comment: Thanks a lot, was not aware of the .Net extension. Yes the PHP is on the same server, we have the certificate but need the key. We intend to use CURL to make the SOAP call, which in turn needs to sign the certificate with the private key.